# Debug Jest tests inside Nrwl.nx Angular workspace with Visual Studio Code debugger

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, jestjs, zone.js, nrwl-nx

Im using Visual Studio Code, and Im trying to debug Jest tests inside of a Nrwl.Nx workspace for Angular.

Here is what I've tried so far:

launch.json

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [

    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Jest All Tests",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/Web/Finance/client-app/node_modules/.bin/jest",
      "args": ["--runInBand"],
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/src/Web/Finance/client-app/apps/finance",
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
      "disableOptimisticBPs": true,
      "windows": {
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/Web/Finance/client-app/node_modules/jest/bin/jest"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

app.component.spec.ts

```
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone.js';
import 'zone.js/dist/async-test.js';
import 'zone.js/dist/proxy.js';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [AppComponent],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
  it('should create the app', async(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  }));
});
```

Originally, I ran the app.component.spec.ts test without importing anything from zone.js/dist, but when I would run the debugger in VS Code, I would get this:

```
Failed: "Zone is needed for the async() test helper but could not be found. Please make sure that your environment includes zone.js/dist/zone.js"
```

So I imported the zone.js/dist files you see in app.component.spec.ts

Now when I run the debugger in VS Code, I get this:

```
Expected to be running in 'ProxyZone', but it was not found.

      at Function.Object.<anonymous>.ProxyZoneSpec.assertPresent (../../node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:42:19)
      at runInTestZone (../../node_modules/zone.js/dist/async-test.js:202:23)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../../node_modules/zone.js/dist/async-test.js:168:17)
```

Doing internet searches has not provided me any information about how to troubleshoot this error.